# Which method provides a better user experience?

Tags: ecommerce, cms, user-experience

We have a CMS e-commerce website and sell pet foods. But unlike any e-commerce site, our customers do not buy the products for themselves. Our customers buy products to be sent to the animal rights activists defined on our site. These activists, with some publications (such as Twitter posts), encourage the purchase of products for themselves.

Here, we have 2 different options.

1. Activists will just share our website link and customers will choose
   the activist's address as a product variation. (But awkwardly, users
   hardly predicts this and the activist has to make a statement every
   time.)
2. We will create a category for every activist. Activists will share
   our website link with the category (activist) slug
   (domain.com/activist-slug). Users will easily add products to cart
   for that activist but in this method we have to create hundreds of
   copy products for each activist (category) due to CMS limitations.

Which method do you advice? Do you have any better solutions which won't force our CMS limitations?

Answer (score 2):

Neither. Create a single `/buy-product` page with a form that users can select the activist's name.

Make that page work with arguments in the URL. For example `/buy-product/?activistName=Sarah`. So when the page loads, the form address and name are pre - populated with Sarah's information. Then the user will just have to select what to buy and press submit.

This way you end up with one page *and* the users will not have to fill the activist's address etc.

Comment: Well, the CMS does not offer any kind of feature like that and we don't have the option to edit the CMS.

Comment: It would be worth paying a developer to build additional functionality into the CMS, or considering switching CMSs. Addresses are not product variations and you are going to risk Google blacklisting if you go with either 1 or 2. Addresses are shipping information - there's got to be a way to prefill that information without having to have multiple variants, copies, or categories for the actual products.

Comment: @WebElaine It is really NOT possible to add any functionality into the CMS. Switching CMS is a way harder option that we don't want to approach for now. The first method is actually in use and is nice with Google. Because we don't provide addresses directly in the product variations but activists' name. So, I'm sorry for the mess I've caused about that topic.